# async.series execute callback before finish current

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

here is the structure

```
var invalid = false;

async.series([
   function(callback)
   {
      someAsync.do(something, function(data)
      {
         if(data == null) invalid = true;

         callback();
      }
   },
   function(callback)
   {
      if(invalid) callback();

      someAsync.doSomethingImportant(something, function(data)
      {
         if(data == null) invalid = true;

         callback();
   }
], function()
{
   if(invalid) doThis();
   else doThat();
});
```

The problem is that the second async function NEEDS that first async has worked successfully.

Sometimes async.series calls the callback() before the statement `invalid = true` and crashes my app. Also, sometimes it works.

Could you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

Instead of using my own `error control`, I used it's default:

```
async.series([
   function(callback)
   {
      someAsync.do(something, function(data)
      {
         if(data == null) callback(true);
         else callback();
      }
   },
   function(callback)
   {    
      someAsync.doSomethingImportant(something, function(data)
      {
         if(data == null) callback(true);
         else callback();
   }
], function(invalid)
{
   if(invalid) doThis();
   else doThat();
});
```

If you pass `callback(err)`, it will skip all other asyncs and execute the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, but if you are depended on the result of the first function, you could try using [async.waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall):

```
async.waterfall([
   function(callback)
   {
      someAsync.do(something, callback);
   },
   function(data, callback)
   {
      if(data == null) { 
          callback(new Error('no data'));
      } else {
          someAsync.doSomethingImportant(something, callback)
      }
   },
   function (data, callback) {
      if (data == null) { 
          callback(new Error('no data'));
      } else {
          callback();
      }
   }
], function(err)
{
   if (err) { 
       doError();
   } else {
       doThat();
   }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:

```
[function a () { async_1(); },
 function b () { async_2(); }]

function c () {}
```

what you need is

```
function a () {
    async_1(function (data) {
        function b (data) {
            async_2(function (result) {
                function c (success) { console.log(success); }
                c(result);
            });
        }

        b(data);
    });
}
```

Now there is no race.

When a finishes, call b, when b finishes, call c.

This can get really ugly, so tools like `Promises` are used to turn this into:

```
async_1()
    .then(async_2())
    .then(c);
```

It might not really be *that* clean, if you need to pass data around (and not just wait for each one to be finiahed) in turn)...  ...but promises are very powerful for this kind of work.

Comment: You just removed async.js... I don't want that.

Comment: I didn't remove asynchronous code, I made the second call depend on the resolution of the first call, and I made the third call depend on the resolution of the second call... All of the actual calls can still be asynchronous. This is how this is done. If you fire a and then b at the same time, then they will race. You have no way of deciding which finishes first. The solution is to call b inside of a's callback, and to call c inside of b's callback, if what you want is code that happens in-order, but asynchronous to the program. And if it's not, then you need to rephrase the problem.

Comment: I'm using it to avoid what you just did, a "callback hell".

Comment: You didn't mention you were using `async.js`. If you had, you could read the API for `async.js`... There are dozens of higher-order solutions I could have given, as regards Promises, functional async et cetera.